# subprocess function displaying odd output

Tags: python, subprocess

I've got a function `def tldomaint` that executes the Tasklist command via a subprocess `call_checkout`. All is working as expected but I'm getting odd output from TaskList. I'm not sure if it's due to my error capturing or if its just an oddity of Tasklist. I'm hoping someone can help pin-point the issue.

Output example:

```
Attempting to make remote connections and gather data:

Targeted User: xpuser

ERROR: The RPC server is unavailable.

1
WARNING: User credentials cannot be used for local connections

ERROR: The RPC server is unavailable.

1
```

The `1` in the output is the oddity I'm referring to.

Below is the function.

```
def tldomaint(serverlist, domain, username, password, targetuser):
    nlist = serverlist
    print "\nAttempting to make remote connections and gather data:\n"
    print "Targeted User: {0}\n" .format(targetuser)
    for serverl in nlist:
        try:
            out = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/S", serverl, "/U", domain + "\\" + username, "/P", password, "/FO", "List", "/FI", "USERNAME eq %s\\%s" % (domain, targetuser)])
            users = [item for item in out.split() if domain in item and targetuser in item]
            sortedl = set(users)
            for name in sortedl: 
                if name in sortedl != '':
                    print "Targeted User Found On {0}\n" .format(serverl)
                    print name
                else:
                    print "User Not Found"            
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.returncode)
    return sortedl
```

Comment: Every output line from a command is appended with `\n`, you're adding this on your own as well.. `print "Targeted User Found On {0}\n"` will print `user\n` + `\n`..

Comment: @Torxed thanks for pointing that out, I have amended my code and will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the process return code:

```
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.returncode)
```

From the [`subprocess.check_output()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a `CalledProcessError`.

When an error occured, the `tasklist` writes an error message to `stderr`, and sets the exit code to 1. `subprocess.check_output()` then raises the `CalledProcessError` exception (as documented) and you catch that exception and then print the return code.

Remove the `print()` statement and your mysterious `1`s will go away.

If you wanted to handle the problem in Python, redirect `stderr` to `stdout`; the exception will still be raised but you can read the output still:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/S", serverl, "/U",
                               domain + "\\" + username, "/P", password, "/FO", "List", 
                               "/FI", "USERNAME eq %s\\%s" % (domain, targetuser)],
                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

and in your exception handler:

```
except CalledProcessError as e:
    errormessage = e.output
    # do something with the error message
```

Comment: Arr ok i understand, is there a better way for me to handle these errors in your opinion? nested if statements on the except?

Comment: What do you want to happen with such an exception instead? It's fine that you catch the exception here.

Comment: maybe `if e.message == blabla` etc?

Comment: well id like to print the server being connected to that errored and get rid of the `1` in the output. so im guessing a nested if with the relevant conditions for the messages? I can get rid of the `1` now no probs (seeing as you so kindly pointed out the issue ^^_)

Comment: Thanks a lot I will have a play.